# Can I publish a paper in mathematics education on a computer program?

Tags: publications, phd, mathematics, education

I am a PhD student in mathematics education. As a part of my thesis, in the last year I designed a learning environment for tablets, similar to a computer game. The program is designed for children ages 6-10.

Up until now, I have not tested the program with any children, only some preliminary tests with fellow students.

Is it possible to publish this?

The program is quite complex and I fear that a single article detailing the program structure and the mathematics it can transport as well as the findings in the working sessions and interviews with the children may turn out to be too long.

Comment: The program doesn't seem to serve any value unless it teaches children something. So, I don't see how the program can be published without any regard for the teaching merit. If the program is too complicated to present in a single paper, then present a sub-program.

Comment: Why not ask your advisor?  Also, surely you can search the literature to look for other papers on similar topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with user2768's comment that it will be most convincing if you can publish a user study and/or test of the program's impact. However, if your program is designed around some part of learning theory that is important but hard to implement, or focuses on a neglected area of mathematics, the program itself may generate interest. You allude to interviews with children when designing the program--so if you can illuminate what the misconceptions are that kids have (or other needs you found) and how the program is designed to address those, that might be compelling.

You may want to take a look at the Bootstrap project, which started as a teacher's classroom tool to teach algebra and became a dissertation topic and then an educational tool.  http://www.bootstrapworld.org/community/

It's also not fully clear to me how far along in your thesis you are. You'd benefit from reading about Design-Based Research (see, e.g., the 2004 special issue of the Journal of Learning Sciences, starting with this article by Barab & Squire: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1207/s15327809jls1301_1?journalCode=hlns20), and possibly also this conference paper on how to build that into a dissertation: http://ro.ecu.edu.au/ecuworks/1612/ This method may offer you a framework to help you publish design work-in-progress, as well as knowledge you gain as you test and develop it.

Also, you may want to ask your advisor about good outlets to publish this, and whether getting a paper out at this point is a top goal. Since most education conferences are non-archival (double-check whether the individual conference publishes archival proceedings), this may also be a good thing to submit to a conference.

Answer (score 0):

Publishing an article about software just because it was difficult to write, is usually not enough. Software does not receive the recognition as research results. And articles describing how a specific software was written is of almost no interest to other readers.

My personal advice: Publish the software as open source to GitHub or similar. Always mention it when you publish or give talks covering your software. People will recognize your work.